# How to get wallets to recognize instructions (instead of having "unknown instruction") within a transaction?

Tags: transactions, metadata, wallet, security, instructions

When sending a transaction, in the wallet confirmation step, in some programs *?the wallet?* seems to recognize what the instruction does, whereas in others it just lists the accounts that get written to.

- What entity is responsible for identifying what a particular instruction does (wallet provider?/solana?), and can that data be passed in somehow ?

Judging from [@solana/web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#) docs, there's nothing that can be passed there to add metadata to the instruction.

I'm sure it would be of great use to the community to have more specific/human readable and verifiable transaction data versus blindly trusting 'unknown instructions'.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruction data is opaque to the runtime. Only the declaring program knows how to interpret it.  Every program that a wallet (or explorer, etc) can display instruction or account data for has an explicit parser implementation